# bitcoinjs-lib package and stack Error: Can't find Python executable on Windows with python 3.x.x

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

Trying to install the package bitcoinjs-lib I receive the following error:

```
> tiny-secp256k1@1.0.1 install C:\project\server\node_modules\tiny-secp256k1
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\project\server\node_modules\tiny-secp256k1>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\.                                .\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable                                .
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\project\server\node_modules\tiny-secp256k1
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN my_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN my_project@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tiny-secp256k1@1.0.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tiny-secp256k1@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-07T01_26_57_441Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                               57_470Z-debug.log
```

I went to node-gyp npm page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp and I found that it does not support python v3.x.x

I researched and found some workarounds, however, all of them require actions by the user side and are tied to a particular OS.

I´m using Windows 7 (with Node v8.9.1) and python 3.6.4.

Is there a way to install the dependency and be able to share the package with other users (no matter OS or python version)?
Can anyone provide some kind of input?

I never went through this with a npm package so I´m really stuck and cannot find a proper solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you wan't to share your web application, I would suggest going with `docker`. It will also require `docker` dependency, at least it will be the one dependency and pretty standard. And it will be easier to run node on linux within a container, rather than on windows.

Comment: Well it does say `you can set the PYTHON env variable` which IMHO is not really OS specific. Nothing stopping you having multiple python installs and there's even tools to manage that. You also appear to be using a system installed nodejs, which also is not really ideal and there are things to manage multiple version installs of that as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes. I thought about that. However, my concern is. Let´s say that I have another python version and I define the path to python/27. Then, I share my Node project with others (people using Linux, OSX or even Windows...). Do they have to follow the same process...? Install python2.7, set the path to that version if you have other, etc? Or, is there a way to automate this? I suppose that there are people who know less than I and could get stuck as well. I will appreciate any suggestion. Thanks a lot